# Is there any native functionality available in wso2 esb for fetching the data from multiple excel file sheets?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i want to extract the data from multiple sheets of excel files using wso2 esb or wso2 dss functionality. Just i want to do those task with native components of wso2 only not with custom class mediator.

Is it possible means please someone guide me with some samples or steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DSS you can add an excel file as datasource, and then specify a query where you tell it the worksheet and columns to retrieve as follows. There is a json and xml sample 'query' both exposed as a resource. You can add configs for more excel sheets or create separate DataServices.

```
<data name="excel-ds" transports="http https">
    <config id="SAMPLE">
        <property name="excel_datasource">/file/path/sample.xlsx</property>
    </config>
    <query id="GET_JSON" useConfig="SAMPLE">
        <excel>
            <workbookname>sampledata</workbookname>
            <hasheader>true</hasheader>
            <startingrow>2</startingrow>
            <maxrowcount>-1</maxrowcount>
        </excel>
        <result outputType="json">{
      "Rows": {
         "Row": [
          {
          "EMPnr": "$EMPnr",
          "Name": "$name",
          "Email": "$email"
          }
        ]
      }
      }</result>
    </query>

    <query id="GET_XML" useConfig="SAMPLE">
        <excel>
            <workbookname>samplesheet</workbookname>
            <hasheader>true</hasheader>
            <startingrow>2</startingrow>
            <maxrowcount>-1</maxrowcount>
        </excel>
        <result element="Rows" rowName="Row">
            <element column="empnr" name="Empnr" xsdType="string"/>
            <element column="name" name="Name" xsdType="string"/>
            <element column="email" name="Email" xsdType="string"/>
        </result>
    </query>

    <resource method="GET" path="samplejson">
        <call-query href="GET_JSON"/>
    </resource>
    <resource method="GET" path="samplexml">
        <call-query href="GET_XML"/>
    </resource>
</data>
```

For documentation check [wso2.com](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+Excel+Data+as+a+Data+Service)

Comment: Thanks. First i want to know one thing in this sample. What is sampledata/samplesheet in excel config? Its a sheet name or excel file name? in this method can we fetch multiple sheets data? Please let me know & suggest the solutions to do.

Comment: You said, " can add configs for more excel sheets or create separate DataServices" suppose if i have 10 sheets in single excel file means should create 10 configs or 10 data services?? other than this, is there any solutions? is there any way to pass like ".*.xlsx"  inside of workbook attribute in excel config.

Comment: sampledata/samplesheet are sheet names within a excel file. The config points to a specific excel file. You cannot use wildcards as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you. So we cant use dss option for multiple as well as dynamic files right?

Comment: No, the DSS does not really do dynamic files. You would probably have to build a custom component (mediator, messageBuilder) for the Enterprise Integrator, using pretty much the same principles as the DSS.  Enterprise Integrator can read files from the filesystem but does not understand Excel files out of the box.